# multitwitch style url rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to recreate the url rewriting that multitwitch.tv uses however am having issues in doing this as google is being unhelpful thinking I want to remove trailing slashes.

I'm trying to effectively do this:

`site.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee`

`site.com?aaa&bbb&ccc&ddd&eee`

Although multitwitch's source is public on Github it's python and not PHP with a .htaccess file so I've not been able to solve this for a while now.

Any help will be greatly accepted.

user inputted url: site.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee 
rewrite to: site.com?aaa&bbb&ccc&ddd&eee

.htaccess:

`Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?channels=$1    [NC,L]`

php:

`<?php 
        foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
           echo $key;
        }
    ?>`

Comment: Huh? You didn't provide any real info. You need to state what your original url is, what you want to rewrite that url to and the current code you have tried.

Comment: user inputted url: site.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee
rewrite to: site.com?aaa&bbb&ccc&ddd&eee

code tried:

`Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?channels=$1    [NC,L]`

and the php to read it:

`<ul>
<?php 
 foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
    echo '<li>' . $key . '</li>';
 }
?>
</ul>`

Comment: Add the code to your question in a readable format not the comments.

Comment: am adding it to the post and not a comment as formatting isn't working there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you want a bunch of levels deep. It might be easier to handle that in php rather than creating a rule for every sub directory added in the URI.
So I would probably do something like this. This will send every request to PHP.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule index\.php - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [NC,L]
```

Then you can type in `http://example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd`

In PHP in your `index.php` you can then do

```
<?php

   $aURI = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
   print_r($aURI);exit;
?>
```

Then use the parts as you need them. You could even count the number of pieces in the new array and based on that you can do stuff. This way you don't have to have a .htaccess rule for every level you want to add to the URL.

Comment: thanks very much, this worked exactly how I needed it to work,